# Wikimedia Commons not working properly from IE 8

Tags: internet-explorer-8

It happens fairly often that a page on [Wikimedia Commons](http://commons.wikimedia.org/) doesn't load in IE. This happens to me on both machines I use, each one Windows 7 with IE 8. The page just loads endlessly (or connects—can't really tell) and timeouts after a while. Repeated attempts (trying to load the same page in 5 to 10 tabs) sometimes work, but sometimes it takes a lot more tries.

As far as I can tell, no other program is affected—Firefox or PowerShell have no trouble loading the page. Also, when I use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) it seems to load fine on the first try as well.

Anyone has an idea what might be going on? I didn't change any settings that I am aware of (and most likely didn't do so in the same way on both machines).

***Preemptive note:*** I don't need advice in the form of »Use another browser instead.«.

Comment: Do you have any proxies that you're using?

Comment: Not when not using Fiddler. And in that case it works.

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce with the following setup:

```
OS: Windows 7 Enterprise
System-type: 64-bit Operating System
Browser: Internet Explorer 8
Version: 8.0.7600.16385
HTTP Headers:
    GET / HTTP/1.1
    Accept: application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, application/x-shockwave-flash, */*
    Accept-Language: en-US
    User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    Host: localhost:8888
    Connection: Keep-Alive
```

What other information do you have for your setup?